# Android: HashMap vs WeakHashMap vs SparseArray in terms of garbage collection

Tags: android, hashmap, android-sparsearray

In Java, a `HashMap` object that is specified as a key is not eligible for garbage collection. A `WeakHashMap` object that is specified as a key is still eligible for garbage collection

My question is in Android, what is the behavior of `SparseArray` in terms of garbage collection? Is it more like `HashMap` or more like `WeakHashMap`

Comment: _In Java, a HashMap object that is specified as a key is not eligible for garbage collection. A WeakHashMap object that is specified as a key is still eligible for garbage collection_ - this makes _very_ little sense.

Comment: what is eligible or not for GC is based on _reachability_; be that strong (by default) for `HashMap` or weak for `WeakHashMap`. until you understand what this means - you will not be able to correctly use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SparseArray` works very similarly to a `Map<Integer, Object>`.

The key differences are that it does not cast or auto-box anything, and that it uses a binary search to find entries not a hash lookup.

The references inside are strong references, like the majority in Java.

If you wanted, you could store `WeakReference`s in a `SparseArray`, just like you could any other `Object`.